# How To Get A For Loop To Affect Each Individual Object

Tags: python, for-loop, increment, maya, autodesk

folks!  My question deals with a Python exercise that I'm currently trying to work out (well, to be more specific, the program is Autodesk Maya, but I'm using Python coding).  The exercise involves taking a number of objects (spheres) contained in an array/list, and then using an increment variable to have them move in an offset animation.  In other words, I want the first sphere to move, then the next spheres to move in a delayed time, then the next sphere with a more delayed time, etc.

The code that I have is as follows:

```
    spheres = mc.ls(selection=True)
    count=0

    for i in range(len(spheres)):
        count+=2
        mc.selectKey(spheres)
        mc.keyframe(edit=True, relative=True, timeChange=count)
        print spheres(i)
```

The spheres are my objects, and as I said, I want the first to move normally in the timeline, then the next sphere to move with a delayed time of two, then the next to move with a delayed time of four, so on and so forth.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
E

Comment: What's the problem with your code? Does it raise an exception? Move all the objects at the same time instead of what you wanted? Or what?

Comment: The problem was identified as the list not being callable.  Also, as seen below, when done correctly, it will only move one sphere at a time, and if more than one is selected, then they will have the same delay time instead of it being incremented (+2, then +4, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not actually setting the keyframe on the individual sphere; it looks like you're setting it on all spheres

Your `for` loop is generally bad form, but also less useful. Try changing it to this:

```
spheres = mc.ls(selection=True)
count=0

for sphere in spheres:
    count += 2
    mc.selectKey(sphere) # only selecting the one sphere!
    mc.keyframe(edit=True, relative=True, timeChange=count)
    print sphere # no need to look up the element
                 # which by the way should have been [i] not (i)
```

Output:

[image]

The keyframes were all lined up originally, but now offset by two frames each from the previous.

Comment: I have selected one sphere, and it worked just fine, it is much appreciated.  However, I want it so the increment will affect all the spheres, one by +2, another by +4, etc.  Is this possible?

Comment: It's working for me. Be sure to select all the spheres at once, since if you run it multiple times the count is always reset to 0.

Comment: If I select all the spheres at once, then the increment will affect all spheres drastically.  Instead of starting at keyframes 1 (sphere 1), 3 (sphere 2), 5 (sphere 3), etc., they all jump to the total number incremented (which in my case, since the increment is 2 and there are four spheres, would push them to not take action until keyframe 20).

Again, selecting one sphere at a time helps it work with no issues, but then it wouldn't exactly be working as a for loop, you know?

Comment: @Ashendis added an image to show the output, when I had multiple spheres selected, all animating from 1-10. Is this not what you want, or not what you're getting?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I want, but unfortunately not what I am getting.  :(

Question: In your code, you have "sphere" instead of "spheres".  But when I use "sphere", it's highlighted as a MEL statement (blue and italicized), and did not work for me.

Comment: `for sphere in spheres` is saying "execute the following code on each element of `spheres`, with the element stored in object `sphere` each time". Don't worry about MEL highlighting; you're in Python. The code works for me if I literally copy and paste it into Maya's script editor.

Comment: Just for clarity's sake: If instead of "sphere" I put "i", or another kind of arbitrary value like "x" or "apple" (lol), would it still work as long as the same protocol was in place?

Comment: go ahead and try it! :)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't told us what the problem is, but I have a guess. (If I've guessed wrong, please elaborate your question, and I'll delete my answer.)

Are you getting an exception like this?

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
----> 1 print spheres(i)

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

You claim that you have an "array/list" of spheres. If `spheres` is a `list` (or `array` or almost any other kind of collection) you index it using the `[]` operator. The `()` operator is used for *function calls*, not indexing. You're trying to call that `list` as if it were a function, passing it `i` as an argument, instead of trying to access that `list` as a sequence, getting the `i`th element.

To fix it:

```
print spheres[i]
```

Comment: That did help, thank you.  It has been a long time since I've coded in Python, so my apologies for my bad form!  :)